# how can i get all the id of the employee of the same name

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

i want to write a GORM query which can list me id of all the employee with the same name

DB format is:

```
|id|Department|EMPLOYEE| DATE |
|01|   D01    |   A    |Date01|
|02|   D03    |   B    |Date03|
|03|   D02    |   B    |Date04|
|04|   D04    |   C    |Date05|
|05|   D05    |   A    |Date03|
|06|   D01    |   B    |Date02|
|07|   D02    |   A    |Date04|
|08|   D04    |   A    |Date05|
|09|   D04    |   C    |Date01|
|10|   D05    |   A    |Date02|
```

Result should be like

```
|EMPLOYEE|       id       |
|   A    | 01,05,07,08,10 |
|   B    |    02,03,06    |
|   C    |      04,09     |
```

Comment: It would be easier if the result could look like
    |Employee|id|
    |A|01|
    …
    |A|10|
    |B|02|
    …
    |B|06|
    |C|04|
    |C|09|
because this could be the result of an SQL `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` column is a collection so it's better to call that `ids` instead.

Handling a row inside a row with sql is not very easy to understand for your colleagues and I would only use it, if you have to load a lot of data and you may run into performance problems.

Hence, I would suggest a simple `findAllByEmployee` query and `group by Employee` in your java code.

If you want to save some bandwidth and cpu because of object dehydration, you could use a [criteria](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#criteria) to only load the needed properties:

```
def result = Empoloyee.createCriteria().list{
    projections {
        property 'id'
        property 'EMPOLYEE'
    }
    // Paging if needed
}

def empolyeeToIdsMap = result.groupBy {it.EMPLOYEE}
```

Disclaimer:
Didn't tried the code, can contain bugs.